# Effective way to read from PostgreSQL database on website

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, database-connection, vaadin

I have database with 2 entities: Shops, Products. Every product got some columns with his description and id of shop where u can get it as a FK. Shops got some columns with description also.

I want to TreeTable list of Shops. When u will expand tree under every shop u will got a list of products in this shop.

As i said im using Vaadin TreeTable, JDBC driver to connect with PostgreSQL database.

Select shops (about 900 rows) is extremaly fast. Less then 1s. However opening statement, selecting all products per shop and closing it is killing my DB.

Page is loading 7-11 s even if i will got 1 product in one shop. So im guessing that Opening and closing statement is a main problem.

**EDIT:** common situation is that in one shop there is only 1-2 products. No more.

I have posted already what i did in 5 steps, however if u need rly code i will post some parts
It is common use of JDBC however im asking what if i need to get many rows, or website is used by many users. What are best practices of using JDBC to make it faster.

My code:

Opening connection:

```
//in db helper class

Connection conn = null;

void openConnection(){
     static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";  
     static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/shops";
     static final String USER = "username";
     static final String PASS = "password";

     try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);
     }catch(SQLException se){
        se.printStackTrace();
     }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
 }

 List<Shop> getAllShops(){
     Statement stmt = null;
     try{
       stmt = conn.createStatement();
       ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
       while(rs.next()){
           //save rs into Shop object
       }
       rs.close();
     }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
     }finally{
     try{
        if(stmt!=null)
           conn.close();
        }catch(SQLException se){
     }
  }

 //method to get operations is exacly the same but im passing Shop int id into method

  void closeConnection(){
       if(connection != null)
           conn.close();
  }

  //in some layout class
  void createAndFillTableMethod(){
     //create table

      DatabaseHelper db = new DatabaseHelper();
      List<Shop> ls = new ArrayList<Shop>();
      ls = getAllShops();

      for(Shop shop: ls){
          List<Product> lp = new ArrayList<Product>();
          lp = getAllProducts(shop.id);

          //add shop to table
          //add lp list as a childs of shop to table
      }
      db.closeConnection();
 }
```

ps: i could skip some try catches.

Comment: Ok, what did you try ?

Comment: how many products are there per shop?  1000 rows in 1s for the shops does not sound fast at all.  There might already be a problem with your channel to the DB or your DB in general.  Well it all depends on the data and this is a very broad question...

Comment: @cfrick im asking about good practices of connecting to database. i think that there is a problem. Check code. Getting only list of shops is extremaly fast. but when i add getting products... it slows down as hell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. I have found somewhere some good habits when connecting to database by website.

What i have done:

1. Added a session events to my Vaadin Servlet.
2. On session start: openning connection with PostgreSQL database.
3. On session close: closing opened connection.

What is more:

To prevent multiple opened connection (by refreshing with F5 button) i surround a open connection with `synchronized` statement and add a flag.

What about statements and result sets:

These stay the same. Opening before every select and closing after execute and save results.